# Quelle est la différence entre « acolyte » et « comparse » ?

Tags: sens

Larousse a ceci à dire au sujet des mots « acolyte », « comparse » et « complice » :

> Ces trois mots figurant souvent dans les mêmes contextes expriment des nuances dans le degré de participation à une affaire suspecte : alors qu'un complice y prend une part active, le comparse n'y joue qu'un rôle sans importance et l'acolyte se borne à accompagner le meneur.

Alors qu'il ne fait aucun doute que le degré de participation d'un complice est supérieur à celui des deux autres, la différence entre ces derniers est loin de m'être claire.

*Larousse* donne les définitions suivantes.

[Acolyte](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/acolyte/777) : individu qui en aide un autre dans des actions peu recommandables ; complice.

[Comparse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/comparse/17615) : personnage muet ou de très peu d'importance au théâtre.

L'*Académie française*, quant à elle, définit les deux mots comme suit.

[Acolyte](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A0407) : compagnon, complice, subalterne qu’une personne traîne toujours à sa suite.

[Comparse](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C3203) : personne qui, dans une affaire, ne joue qu’un rôle mineur.

Lequel des deux, alors, participe à un degré supérieur ?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=m%27est+loin+d%27%C3%AAtre%2Cest+loin+de+m%27%C3%AAtre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de différence de degré significative entre ***acolyte*** et ***comparse*** dans le contexte décrit dans la question, les deux y sont couramment et indifféremment employés.

On les retrouve par exemple pour les mêmes personnes dans ces deux pages de la chaine Public Sénat :

> *Concernant l'affaire Benalla, le parquet de Paris a ouvert une information judiciaire confiée à un juge d'instruction, notamment pour "violences en réunion" et "immixtion dans l'exercice d'une fonction publique", après les violences commises sur deux manifestants le 1er Mai par **Alexandre Benalla et son comparse Vincent Crase**, alors qu'ils étaient simples "observateurs" au sein des forces de l'ordre.*
>
> [*La commission d'enquête du Sénat n'exclut plus d'auditionner Alexandre Benalla*](https://www.publicsenat.fr/article/politique/la-commission-d-enquete-du-senat-n-exclut-plus-d-auditionner-alexandre-benalla), Juil. 2018

> *En ce qui concerne les deux principaux protagonistes de l'affaire, **Alexandre Benalla et son acolyte Vincent Crase**, ils ont demandé au Bureau du Sénat "de saisir le ministère public" de leurs déclarations sous serment, "susceptibles de donner lieu à des poursuites pour faux témoignage".*
>
> [*Affaire Benalla : épilogue en vue au Sénat*](https://www.publicsenat.fr/article/politique/affaire-benalla-epilogue-en-vue-au-senat-139352), mars 2019

Answer (score 0):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acolyte)) **acolyte**  − P. ext., péj., le plus souvent au plur. **Complice** :

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comparse))  **comparse** **B.** − P. ext.
> **1.** **Personne ne jouant qu'un rôle très effacé dans une affaire, dans une société; caractère falot**
> − Spéc. **Complice ne jouant généralement qu'un rôle secondaire** :
> •  Les principaux coupables eurent les yeux crevés, à la manière byzantine; aux comparses on coupa simplement le nez, les mains ou les pieds, ... Grousset, L'Épopée des croisades,1939, p. 58.

La remarque suivante du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acolyte) sur « acolyte » est utile dans le sens de préciser le sens.

> **Rem**. Le sens relig., qui représente la moitié des emplois au sing., ne recouvre plus que le cinquième des emplois au plur. L'expr. *deux acolytes*, qui représentait la moitié des ex. au xix<sup>e</sup>s., n'en représente plus que le quart au xx<sup>e</sup>s., où le terme se désacralise alors que l'emploi relig. reste techn.

La moitié des exemples au pluriel au  xix<sup>e</sup>s. est sous forme de « deux acolytes », une expression qui laisse entendre une participation égale dans l'activité criminelle. On associe donc dans la définition en ce siècle-là l'idée de complicité à parts égales ; cela persiste au xx<sup>e</sup>s. bien que le nombre des exemples au pluriel baisse pour devenir seulement le quart. Plutôt qu'un glissement du sens on doit suspecter un changement du modus opérandi des criminels, il me semble.  Il est toujours assez certain que l'acolyte est  considéré comme étant entaché à un degré comparable de la faute qui est reprochée.  Les définitions du TLFi à l'appui, on peut avec peu de risque d'erreur conclure que la participation de l'acolyte dans un crime donné est jugée être d'un degré supérieur à celle du comparse.